# Composer/Laravel fresh install error

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I've got a brand new laravel installation on DigitalOcean, which I'm attempting to run a basic `composer update' on. However, I'm seeing the following error come up every time I try to update. I can't solve the problem with composer cacheclear, deleting the vendor/compiled.php file, or even reinstalling the entire framework.

I don't understand exactly what the error is in the first place, so I'm a bit lost. Any tips on what's going on?

```
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-update-cmd event returned with an error


[RuntimeException]
  Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundat
  ion\Application::getCachedCompilePath() in /var/www/html/production/vendor/
  laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/ClearCompiledCommand.ph
  p on line 28
```

Comment: This might help:  http://laravel.io/forum/03-24-2015-call-to-undefined-method-illuminatefoundationapplicationgetcachedcompilepath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the `vendor/compiled.php` and run composer update.
Source: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/runtimeexception-on-fresh-install?page=1

Comment: While deleting both vendor/compiled.php AND storage/framework/compiled.php seems to solve it, the problem comes back persistently whenever I install laravel. Do you know what causes it in the first place? Is it an installation error?